# Rails not found after Mac Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, osx-snow-leopard

I just ran an Update on my Snow Leopard and today when I tried to run Rails server I got the following:

> Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest
>   version, simply type:
>
> ```
> $ sudo gem install rails
> ```

On Echo $PATH I get following:

*/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin*

**Update**

Running the command giving above for installing rails did not do any harm. I guess updating process removed previous links of rails. the latest version of Rails and dependencies got installed and things working perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command

```
which rails
```

and see if rails is installed. If it is, add it to your executable path

Comment: it returned /usr/bin/rails. I also edited the Question and added current $PATH content

Comment: Are you using rvm? If you are, try 'rvm gemset list_all', and check for the which version of ruby has rails installed. After that, do 'rvm use version-of-ruby', and try again.

Comment: I am using the default installation of ruby and Rails

Comment: I am thinking that the ruby path got corrupted. Snow Leopard might have installed another version of ruby into the system.

Comment: BTW I have run the command **sudo gem install rails** and its installing things. Lets see how things work

Comment: the command made things perfect. It installed Rails 3.2.2 and other dependencies. I guess Updated removed older versions. It's still using  Ruby 1.8. Thanks for your help. I am still accepting your answer